# how to pull only git logs without pulling the whole file tree and diffs

Tags: git

I have a server that has limited storage space and I need to track a git repository, but I am only interested in the log messages and not the whole repository (blobs, diffs, tags, ...). the repository that I'm willing to track has a large commit history, and above that it stores some large binary files which makes it impossible to sync and pull everything.

now I'm wondering if there a way to pull only git logs from a branch!

and if possible is possible to pull logs after or before a commit hash?

Answer (score 1):

If you interested only in the log messages, you don't need to pull. You could run:

```
git fetch
```

... and then

```
git log --remotes
```

Now you'll see remote commit logs.

To see only remote commits (assuming the branch in question is master):

```
git log --remotes --not master
```

If you can't even fetch, you'll need to ssh the remote repository machine. If you're using Github you could try use its API.